# jdbctemplate BeanProprtyRowMapper for boolean

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Does the BeanProprtyRowMapper will automatically map DB value "0" as false and "1" as true if respective bean field is type boolean?

Comment: Yes it will do that.

Comment: 'BeanPropertyRowMapper'  will convert values into a **Boolean object** with _0=false_ and  _1=true_

Comment: Thanks Jens and Mihir